# Why are some elements undefined in my slider script?

Tags: javascript

I am creating an image slider for JavaScript. I have it so that my left and right arrows display the next image. I was thinking to add a setInterval method to just change the display image every few seconds. I was assuming it would be as easy as calling the function to click the right image every 3 seconds. But I get an error saying

```
index.js:26 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
    at slideRight (index.js:26)
```

Heres my code

```
let sliderImages = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
let arrowLeft = document.getElementById('arrow-left');
let arrowRight = document.getElementById('arrow-right');
let current = 0;

function reset() {
    for(let i = 0; i < sliderImages.length; i++) {
        sliderImages[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}

function startSlider() {
    reset();
    sliderImages[0].style.display = 'block';
}

function slideLeft() {
    reset();
    sliderImages[current - 1].style.display = 'block';
    current --;
}


function slideRight() {
    reset();
    sliderImages[current + 1].style.display = 'block';
    console.log(current);
    current ++;
    console.log(current);
}

arrowLeft.addEventListener('click', function() {
    reset()
    if(current == 0) {
        current = sliderImages.length;
    }
    slideLeft();
});

arrowRight.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if(current == sliderImages.length -1 ) {
        current = -1;
    }

    slideRight();
})
startSlider();

setInterval(slideRight, 3000);
```

Comment: Just FYI: `setInterval()` is not a part of JavaScript. It's a part of the `window` API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem seems to me to be that when you go too far right that index no longer exists in the array, so you need to use the modulus operator when going right:

```
sliderImages[(current + 1) % sliderImages.length].style.display = 'block';
```

And you need to wrap around to the right side when going left too far:

```
sliderImages[current - 1 >= 0 ? 
    current - 1 : sliderImages.length - 1].style.display = 'block';
```

Comment: Thanks this worked and I had consider what Vox said too. I had to wrap my current + 1 in parentheses. Thanks guys I will accept this answer when it allows me to in 3 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in `sliderImages[current + 1]`.

When you reach the lastest image `current + 1` is an out of bound index and the cooresponding entry in sliderImages returns `null`.

You probably need to check something like

```
if (current < sliderImages.length) {
  sliderImages[current + 1].style.display = 'block';
  current++;
}
```